# How cand I align an element vertically aligned with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this site:

[link](http://bagel.dg-site.com/bagel/)

In the left column and there I found a menu

I want that to be aligned to the center menu ... I put a picture below to understand more clearly what I mean.

[image]

**CODE JS:**

```
function centerContent()
{
    var container = $('#secondary');
    var content = $('#primary-sidebar');
    var logo=$('#secondary h1:first-child');
    content.css("margin-top", (container.height()-logo.height()-content.height())/2);
}
```

Can you tell me please which is why it displays the menu too low? Calculation is wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you make it with pure javascript? It's so easy:
`#logo  {
          position: absolute;
          top: 50%;
          transform: translateY(-50%);
       }`
Note that `#logo` it's an selector example. See it works:

https://jsfiddle.net/auww7cr9/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use $(window).height() for the window height and $(document).scrollTop() (space between document start and current scroll height) for calculating the middle position of the screen. Try this:

```
var middleHeight = $(document).scrollTop() + $(window).height() / 2.0;
```